# Domain monotonicity of eigenvalues

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega_{1}$, $\Omega_{2}$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ with smooth boundary and $\Omega_{1} \subsetneq \Omega_{2}$. Let $-\lambda_{1}$ and $-\lambda_{2}$ be the smallest (in magnitude) eigenvalues for the Dirichlet problem on $\Omega_{1}$ and $\Omega_{2}$. That is, for $i = 1, 2$,

\begin{align*}
\Delta \phi_{i} &= -\lambda_{i}\phi_{i} \text{ in } \Omega_{i}\\
\phi_{i} &= 0 \text{ on }\partial \Omega_{i}.
\end{align*}
My question is must $\lambda_{1} > \lambda_{2}$? In particular, must the inequality be a strict inequality?

Answer (score 3):

This is true; the argument I give is based on the variational characterization of the lowest eigenvalue as 
$$
\lambda(\Omega) = \inf_{u \in H^1_0(\Omega)}\frac{\int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2}{\int_\Omega u^2} 
$$
where the infimum is attained exactly by the eigenfunctions. You can find proofs in multiple places by searching for "Rayleigh quotient", for example [Theorem 4 here](http://web.stanford.edu/class/math220b/handouts/eigenvalues.pdf).

Suppose both $\Omega_1$ and $\Omega_2$ have the same lowest Dirichlet eigenvalue (aka fundamental frequency). Let $u_1$ be a function that minimizes the Rayleigh quotient in $H^1_0(\Omega_1)$. Extend it by zero to a function in $H^1_0(\Omega_2)$. By assumption, the extended function minimizes the Rayleigh quotient in $H^1_0(\Omega_2)$, and therefore is an eigenfunction of the Laplacian. But this is impossible since it is not real-analytic: it vanishes identically on $\Omega_2\setminus \Omega_1$.