# Rayleigh quotient strictly increases

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Consider the Rayleigh quotient $$\lambda_{L} := \max_{u \in H^{1}_{0}([0, L])}\frac{-\int_{0}^{L}u'^{2}\, dx}{\int_{0}^{L}u^{2}\, dx}.$$ Is $\lambda_{L}$ strictly increasing in $L$?

Fix an $L_{1}, L_{2} > 0$ with $L_{1} <L_{2}$ and let $u_{1}$ be the maximizer of $\lambda_{L_{1}}$. Extending $u_{1}$ to be zero on $(L_{1}, L_{2}]$ gives a function in $H^{1}_{0}([0, L_{2}])$ and so $\lambda_{L_{1}} \leq \lambda_{L_{2}}$. Now suppose we had $\lambda_{L_{1}} = \lambda_{L_{2}}$. Then for some functions $u \in H^{1}_{0}([0, L_{1}])$ and $v \in H^{1}_{0}([0, L_{2}])$, $$\frac{\int_{0}^{L_{1}}u'^{2}\, dx}{\int_{0}^{L_{1}}u^{2}\, dx} = \frac{\int_{0}^{L_{2}}v'^{2}\, dx}{\int_{0}^{L_{2}}v^{2}\, dx}.$$ How can I derive a contradiction from this?

Comment: That's not a contradiction. For instance, both $u$ and $v$ could be constants. The real contradiction (if there is one ... I have no idea) would come from assuming that when $v$ is the maximizer for $L_2$, that there's some function $u$ for $L_1$ that achieves the same value.

Answer (score 1):

I   [already answered](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1416598)  this in $n$ dimensions, but here is something specific to one-dimensional case: 
$$\max_{u \in H^{1}_{0}([0, L])}\frac{-\int_{0}^{L}u'^{2}\, dx}{\int_{0}^{L}u^{2}\, dx} = - \frac{\pi^2}{L^2}$$
Indeed, [Wirtinger's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wirtinger%27s_inequality_for_functions#Second_version) says that $\int_{0}^{L}u'^{2}\, dx\ge \frac{\pi^2}{L^2} \int_{0}^{L}u^{2}\, dx$, and the function $u(x) = \sin (\pi x/L)$ realizes equality here.